# cannot click a type=button using selenium but works for type=submit

Tags: html, python-2.7, dom, selenium-webdriver

This is the button that I'm trying to click:

```
<button class="button-text-like marg-l-0 float-l desktop-only remove-button" data-bind="click: $root.removeCartItem" type="button"> <i class="gicon-cross"></i> Remove </button>
```

I find and click the button by using the following xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mini-cart-slider"]/li[1]/div/div/div[2]/button').click()
```

However I'm getting an exception when I do that. The type of exception is

```
ElementNotVisibleException
```

This could happen because the element should be removed when I click that remove button. However if I ignore this exception, the item does not seem to be getting removed from the cart.

I'm using the firefox webdriver. When I do a similar function on another button that has the following markup it works fine:

```
<button style="display: inline-block;" type="submit" class="add-cart button wgrid-3w6 wgrid-4w4 marg-l-0">Add to cart</button>
```

The only difference between this button is that it is type ***"submit"*** whereas the button that doesn't work is a type ***"button"***

Is there a different method to click each of these types?

Comment: Which exception exactly?

Comment: '//*[@id="mini-cart-slider"]/li[1]/div/div/div[2]/button', is there a duplicate button along this path?

Comment: no there is no duplicate in that path. Please see my edit I've updated the type of exception I see: ElementNotVisibleException

Comment: ElementNotVisibleException, there are several reasons this might have happened, you do not give the page enough time to load / reload, consider giving it a few second to load before clicking your button. Or the button is on a different window / frame.

Comment: I figured out the solution. This is the case where you have to execute the javascript because the element is actually generated as a result of some action. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was solved by executing a simulated click using the execute_script. The syntax is as follows:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()',driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mini-cart-slider"]/li[1]/div/div/div[2]/button'))
```

Comment: Try sircapsalot's answer. It's less hacky and less error prone and brittle.

Comment: Sure I agree the path is brittle and I've used his suggestions, but it doesn't solve the problem. The issue was that the button is generated by script hence the elementnotvisible exception which is solved exactly by executing click as script.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is your xpath is too brittle.  Your xpath heavily depends on the path being very specific, and any change (even in display ordering) can break it.

Try something less brittle:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mini-cart-slider button')
```

To find your remove button...

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mini-cart-slider button.remove-button')
```

or your add to cart button...

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mini-cart-slider button.add-cart')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am using your suggestion as well.